# What is the name for smoothing out a chart with a gaussian function?

Tags: charts, statistics

I'm having some Saturday chart-fun with corona statistics and am trying to smooth out a time series. Previously i have been using moving averages for this but it's never felt like a good way of visualizing the effects. Today I thought that it should be possible to use a gaussian function, Treating every event as a probability and blur it so parts of it counts over multiple days with most of it being counted the day it happened.
Rough idea:

If someone was infected happened on a monday. add 0.5 to mondays count, 0.2 to sunday and tuesdays count, and 0.05 to saturday and wednesdays count.

I can't be the first one to think of this idea. Does this method have a name?

Comment: For smoothing a time series, take a look at LOESS aka LOWESS. See also smoothing splines. Also, a question about a general approach is more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com instead of SO. Finally, applying any kind of smoothing to a time series is equivalent to making some unstated and possibly unknown assumptions about how the phenomenon works. My advice is omit any smoothing steps and just present the data as they are. If you have some specific model for the phenomenon, i.e. you have known, stated assumptions, then present the model output on top of the raw data so people see both.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because statistics questions belong on https://stats.stackexchange.com, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a special case of [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). In particular, the kernels would be Gaussian in your case.

This is implemented in many Python libraries, e.g.

- seaborn: [sns.kdeplot()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)
- pandas: [df.plot_kde()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde.html)
- scipy.stats: [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html)